# python Tkinter tkFileDialog

Tags: python, tkinter

in short, what's the difference between

```
tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile
```

and

```
tkFileDialog.asksaveasfilename
```

I could not understand from the build in docs

Comment: Learning to program involves a bit of experimentation. You _could_  write a small program that executes each of those functions and see for yourself what happens...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`asksaveasfile` asks the user for a file, then opens that file in write mode and returns it to you so you can write in it.

`asksaveasfilename` asks the user for a file, then returns that file's name. No file is opened; if you want to write to the file, you'll have to open it yourself.

`asksaveasfilename` might be preferred over `asksaveasfile` if you want to do something fancier to the file than just writing data to it. For instance, you might want to first copy the file to another directory as a backup. In which case, you'd prefer to get just the file name so you can perform the copy without having to worry about whether having the file open will cause the copy to fail.

Comment: Actually I understand that both functions asks the user for a filename anyway, as my point here is to create a **new** file. (So why you say 'asks user for a file', like existing one?). If I want to write a new file to the user disk, asksaveasfile should be preferred?

Comment: @user3599803: Tkinter's `asksaveas...` functions allow the user to select an existing file, but if they do, an alert pops up asking them if they want to overwrite the file. Try it & see!

Comment: @Kevin Once the file's been opened in `'w'` mode it's already truncated, so if you use `asksaveasfile` you don't get a chance to back it up.

Comment: Ooh, right. So it's an even better idea to use `asksaveasfilename` than I originally thought :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) wiki:

Similar to:

> First you have to decide if you want to open a file or just want to get a filename in order to open the file on your own. In the first case you should use `tkFileDialog.askopenfile()` in the latter case `tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()`.

then:

> Saving files works in a similar way. You also have two variants of the function, one to get an opened file which you can use to save your data and another to get a file name in order to open the file on your own. These functions are only provided in the single file version. A multiple file version would make no sense.

Comment: I want to write a new file to the user disk, and the dialog should just let him save it in a folder