# File dailog in tkinter

Tags: python, csv, user-interface, tkinter

I have a python tkinter GUI which will allow me to open a csv or Excel file and work on them and save the result in csv or Excel file .I want to save them in the desired location so I used **asksaveasfile** filedailog to get save prompt and it's working fine my problem is I want to save the csv or Excel file with the name , extension, location specified in the save prompt .How can I write my csv file to the field object created?
Here is the code

```
def Save(self):
    Self.filename = filedailog.asksavesafile(defaultextension = ".csv")

    Self.filename.write(self.df.to_csv())
```

I want to save the data frame (df) with the specified name and to the specified location and extension

Comment: whats the problem with current code? I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: Yes it seems to run fine for me

Comment: I want to save a csv file .In the above code didn't mentioned name and extension of the file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [writing-a-pandas-dataframe-to-csv-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281),  [`asksaveasfilename`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39792020/7414759)

Comment: No I want to save the data frame to csv file with name and extension and location specified by the user .How can I get them?

Comment: filedialog.asksaveasfile() returns a file object like you would get with an open() statement. You can the simply just .write() your data to it. If you want the full filepath with extension, you can use filedialog.asksaveasfilename() instead. Does this help?

Comment: I found answer for that . From the fileobject.name would return the path and name and extension that I needed ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able get that name , extension and location that user entered from fileobject.name

```
self.filename = filedailog.asksaveasfile(defaultextension = ".csv")
df.to_csv(filename.name)
```